# And in Organization of BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

I want to cite a standard from IEEE

```
@Standard{IE802,
  Title                    = {IEEE 802.11p},
  Organization             = {Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers},

  Owner                    = {xxxxx},
  Timestamp                = {2016.02.12}
}
```

but now my problem is, as I write my document in german, in my biblograyphy the "and" is translatet to "und". I think it is because `bibtex` read `Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers` as two organizations...
I don't know how to "tell" `bibtex` that this is one organization?

Answer (score 2):

add curly braces to "tell" bibtex that this is one organization.

```
Organization = {{Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers}}
```

should work. Please check

Answer (score 1):

use

```
  Organization = {{Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers}},
```